# Fix the radio buttons (Survey Scale CSS) background color after it is checked and all button less the selected one

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Radio buttons background color is correctly set on hover and checked. But facing issue to fix the color after it is checked and also for others less than the selected.

```css
/*main rating class*/

.rating {
  position: inherit;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: linear-gradient( to left, #f00, #ff0, #0f0);
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating label {
  position: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="rdbRating1">*1. XYZ </label>

  <!-- 1st Radio button list -->

  <div class="rating" id="rdbRating1">
    <input type="radio" value="7" id="7">
    <label for="7">7</label>
    <input type="radio" value="6" id="6">
    <label for="6">6</label>
    <input type="radio" value="5" id="5">
    <label for="5">5</label>
    <input type="radio" value="4" id="4">
    <label for="4">4</label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" id="3">
    <label for="3">3</label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id="2">
    <label for="2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id="1">
    <label for="1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" value="NA" id="NA">
    <label for="NA">NA</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="rdbRating2">*2. ABC </label>

  <!-- 2nd Radio button list -->

  <div class="rating" id="rdbRating2">
    <input type="radio" value="7" id="7">
    <label for="7">7</label>
    <input type="radio" value="6" id="6">
    <label for="6">6</label>
    <input type="radio" value="5" id="5">
    <label for="5">5</label>
    <input type="radio" value="4" id="4">
    <label for="4">4</label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" id="3">
    <label for="3">3</label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id="2">
    <label for="2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id="1">
    <label for="1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" value="NA" id="NA">
    <label for="NA">NA</label>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vanilla javascript for this...

Pretty sure you're looking to select all the elements ***after*** the clicked element on your line of elements. If I am incorrect let me know and I will adjust the answer.

Using a function that checks the next element in your *nodeList* from the selected element, you can embed that function within a ***forEach*** loop and ***eventListener***.

Get the element nodelist to iterate over using `querySelectorAll()`. Then iterate over using `forEach()`. Pass a param to get the iterated value `val`, then run an *eventListener* on that iterated value. Pass the event object through the listener, `e` and use the `target` property to target the element being clicked.

Then use `e.target` to apply a class to the targeted element that will apply style to it.

Then we want to apply style to the remaining siblings in the nodeList that are of the type LABEL. Here we use a helper function [**`nextUntil()`**](https://vanillajstoolkit.com/helpers/nextuntil/) that gets the remaining elements in the ***nodeList*** from the selected element that was triggered by the click event listener to a specified target element within the ***nodelist***.
***NOTE:*** *I added an empty span tag for selection to each of your `rating` child nodes.*

We use the `e.target` and run a *for/in* loop to get the targeted elements we want to apply the *class* to. This is achieved using a conditional within the for loop that checks the type of elements ***nodeName*** is a `LABEL`. Now that we have the labels from start to targeted finish, we apply the class to the selected ***nodeList***.

```js
let rating = document.querySelectorAll('.rating label');

let nextUntil = (elem, selector, filter) => {
  // Setup siblings array
  let siblings = [];
  // Get the next sibling element
  elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
  // As long as a sibling exists
  while (elem) {
    // If we've reached our match, bail
    if (elem.matches(selector)) break;
    // If filtering by a selector, check if the sibling matches
    if (filter && !elem.matches(filter)) {
      elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
      continue;
    }
    // Otherwise, push it to the siblings array
    siblings.push(elem);
    // Get the next sibling element
    elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
  }
  return siblings;
};

// pass the parameters into the function 
let changeBg = (el, eType, target, classname) => {
  // loop over the elements 
  el.forEach((val) => {
    // add an event listener to the current element and pass the event object
    val.addEventListener(eType, (e) => {
      // lets reset the targeted parent elements childNodes class name      
      // if it is set to the class name that sets the BG transparency
      // if user clicks to change the setting they have already set
      for (let i = 0; i < e.target.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (e.target.parentNode.childNodes[i].className === classname) {
          e.target.parentNode.childNodes[i].classList.remove(classname);          
        }
      }
      // use the event target to target the current element being triggered
      e.target.className = classname;
      // target the last element to stop the helper function and pass in the e.target
      let next = nextUntil(e.target, 'span');
      // iterate over the remaining elements
      for (let i in next) {
        // use the index on the values for targetting and apply the class that will style it 
        if (next[i].nodeName === target) {
          next[i].className = classname;
        }
      }
    })
  })
}

// call function and pass in the unique parameters
// iterating over the rating elements
// adding a click listener
// targeting the "LABEL" elements in the nodeList
// adding the class 'rated'
changeBg(rating, 'click', 'LABEL', 'rated');
```

```css
/*main rating class*/

.rating {
  position: inherit;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: linear-gradient( to left, #f00, #ff0, #0f0);
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating label {
  position: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.rated {
  background: transparent !important;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="rdbRating1">*1. XYZ </label>

  <!-- 1st Radio button list -->

  <div class="rating" id="rdbRating1">
    <input type="radio" value="7" id="7">
    <label for="7">7</label>
    <input type="radio" value="6" id="6">
    <label for="6">6</label>
    <input type="radio" value="5" id="5">
    <label for="5">5</label>
    <input type="radio" value="4" id="4">
    <label for="4">4</label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" id="3">
    <label for="3">3</label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id="2">
    <label for="2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id="1">
    <label for="1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" value="NA" id="NA">
    <label for="NA">NA</label>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="rdbRating2">*2. ABC </label>

  <!-- 2nd Radio button list -->

  <div class="rating" id="rdbRating2">
    <input type="radio" value="7" id="7">
    <label for="7">7</label>
    <input type="radio" value="6" id="6">
    <label for="6">6</label>
    <input type="radio" value="5" id="5">
    <label for="5">5</label>
    <input type="radio" value="4" id="4">
    <label for="4">4</label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" id="3">
    <label for="3">3</label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id="2">
    <label for="2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id="1">
    <label for="1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" value="NA" id="NA">
    <label for="NA">NA</label>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Hi Dale, I'm so grateful for your support. It solved my problem and the way you solved the problem and explained it is commendable.

One help or guidance, If the user initially checked the incorrect rating and wishes to decrease.
Then what approach should I follow to add these provision.

Comment: I would target the elements *nodeList* in the event listener prior to the event object target *classList* being defined and remove each *classList* `classname` which is the `rated` class. So in essence, each time you click on an event target and the listener is fired, it resets each elements *classList* by removing the `classname` => `rated`, then the trigger continues on to add the appropriate *classList* => `rated` using the helper function `nextUntil()`

Comment: @tpural see the edited answer, I have added a standard for loop that iterates over the event targets parent node and removes the class name, essentially resetting the element prior to the setting of the bg color by removing transparency.

Comment: Hello Dale, thank you so much for all your help and assistance.